# Perl printing of a hash gives ARRAY(xxxxxxx)

Tags: perl, hash

I know there are many questions already with this kind of subject, but as far as I know (perl beginner so I could be wrong), I'm not using an array so I don't understand where this output comes from

```
$VAR1 = {
  'BridgeMode' => {
    'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5' => {
      'Description' => 'poort1',
      'Duplex' => 'F(a)',
      'Interface' => 'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5',
      'Link' => 'UP',
      'PVID' => '100',
      'Speed' => '10G(a)',
      'Type' => 'A',
      'Vlan100' => {
        'UntaggedPorts' => [
          'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5'
        ]
      },
      'vlanID' => [
        'Vlan100'
      ]
    },
```

Above is the content of my dumper and this is my print statement:

```
my $untaggedInterface = $data{BridgeMode}{"Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5"}{Vlan100}{UntaggedPorts} ;
print "Untagged: $untaggedInterface \n" ;
```

I would expect that the print statement would print "Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5" but instead it shows this:

```
Untagged: ARRAY(0x24a8ec0)
```

**edit - it is possible that there exists an tagged and an untagged:**

```
$VAR1 = {
  'BridgeMode' => {
    'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/12' => {
      'Description' => 'poort5',
      'Duplex' => 'F(a)',
      'Interface' => 'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/12',
      'Link' => 'UP',
      'PVID' => '100',
      'Speed' => '10G(a)',
      'Type' => 'H',
      'Vlan100' => {
        'UntaggedPorts' => [
          'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/12'
        ]
      },
      'Vlan107' => {
        'TaggedPorts' => [
          'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/12'
        ]
      },
```

**edit: printing the content of the array**

```
my @untaggedInterface = $data{BridgeMode}{"Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5"}{Vlan100}{UntaggedPorts} ;
print join(", ", @untaggedInterface) ;
```

stil gives

```
ARRAY(0x1c03a68)
```

Comment: It's not `UntaggedPorts => '...'`. It's `UntaggedPorts => [...]`. The value of the hash element is a reference to an array.

Comment: @ikegami so how would I be able to print the content of UntaggedPorts? Still don't see where this array comes from but Dumper indeed shows it's an array, didn't see the difference between '...' and [...]

Comment: To print the elements of an array, iterate over the elements of the array and print each one. Alternatively, you could pass then to `join` and print the result. You could even interpolate the array in a double-quoted string literal and print the result.

Comment: @ikegami Doesn't make much difference. Updated the question with the commands

Comment: print $data{BridgeMode}{"Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5"}{Vlan100}{UntaggedPorts}[0] ; does the trick

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. The fact that an array was used is a sure sign that there won't always be one value. There might be more. There might be less. In other words, that's an awful solution, which is why I didn't mention it

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an XML conversion. If so, there might well be a better solution to your problem than using XML::Simple.

Comment: No XML conversion but output from a network switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the expected result if you had the following, i.e. a string instead of a string array:

```
'UntaggedPorts' => 'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/12'
```

Otherwise, you must specify the index of the array element:

```
my $untaggedInterface = $data{BridgeMode}{"Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5"}{Vlan100}{UntaggedPorts}[0];
```

Comment: Found it at the same moment as you (see comment) but will give you credit